# Cycles shader colour: values above 1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

A quick question about shader surface colour values in Cycles.

If you set the surface colour of a shader to values greater than 1, for example the diffuse shader in the image below:

[image]

Can it be said that this material is reflecting more energy than it is receiving? e.g. will the albedo of a diffuse shader ever be pushed beyond 1 by increasing the colour values above 1?

Answer (score 5):

If you push your color values above `1` your render will become physically inaccurate. You should try to keep your color values at most 1.

**Glossy Shader with a color value of `1 1 1` vs `50 50 50`**

[image]   [image]

**Diffuse Shader with a color value of `1 1 1` vs `5 5 5`**

[image]   [image]

As you can see once you set the color value above one the shader are emitting more light than they are receiving. If you have no light though the scene will not be illuminated by the shaders because the shaders are not actually emitting light they are acting like a multiplier.

You will also notice that in the render output certain pixels have a color value above `1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that is correct. here is an official doc, the final entry talks about this

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Materials

the gist is that values over 1 and using the "add shader" can cause the material to create light and act as an emission shader. there are times when this might be useful so its not prohibited, but if you don't need it, its not recommended...